# GL_POLYGONMODE don't know how to use properly

Tags: java, opengl

I want to draw an object which its lines are yellow (wireframe) and its fillings are black so i can see the difference. I know that in order to do that i must use glPolygonMode(int arg1, int arg2) but i don't know how to do it properly, here's how I'm doing....

```
  gl1.glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    gl1.glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    gl1.glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl1.glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
```

the problem is this only fills the polygones and forget the lines...

Comment: The code segement you supplied should definitly draw the polygons outlines in black without filling anything. btw: your second call to glColor3d overrides the first one.

Comment: but how can I do this in order to fill and use wireframe at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

To draw a color-filled polygon with outlines of a different color, you will have to draw the model twice:

- In the first pass with polygonmode set to GL_FILL and the colors set to the polygons color.
- In the second draw call you draw the same model with polygonmode set to GL_LINE and with the outline color.

The code will look somehow as follows:

```
gl1.glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
gl1.glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
gl1.glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
//Draw model
gl1.glEnd();

gl1.glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
gl1.glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
gl1.glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
//Draw model again
gl1.glEnd();
```

If you have depth testing enabled, you will have to draw the model a bit closer to the camera in the second pass to pass the depth test. You can do this for example with the second parameter of [glPolygonOffset](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/).

In addition: If there is no good reason for it, you should not use the fixed-function functionality any more since it is deprecated.

Comment: gl1.glColor3d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        gl1.glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
 gl1.glColor3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
 gl1.glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

I just did this and didn't work aswell

Comment: you have to draw the model between GL_FILL and the next call to glColor3d. I update answer

Comment: @pmpc: It probably won't work assuming you have depth testing enabled. The default depth function is `GL_LESS`, and the unfilled lines generate a depth (roughly) equal to what you drew on the last pass, so they fail the depth test. You can either apply a depth offset or disable depth testing between passes. You might think that using a depth function `GL_EQUAL` would do the trick, but that generally doesn't work in multi-pass rendering. _That was all explained in the 2nd to last paragraph of the answer._